# Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers" Angular 4

Tags: angular, api

I am getting next error in my console:

Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Headers".

I have the next code:

```
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { getLocaleDateFormat } from '@angular/common';
// import 'rxjs/Rx';
 // import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!!';
  private apiUrl = 'http://testserver:8083/feedback_api/2/token';
  data: any = {};

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('TEST');
    this.getContact();
    this.getData();
  }


  getData() {
        // add authorization header with jwt token
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Authorization' });
     //   headers.append('Access-Control-Request-Headers', 'Authorization');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic exampletokenexampletokenexampletoken');
        // 'Authorization': 'Basic exampletokenexampletokenexampletoken'
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        console.log(headers);

        // get users from api
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, options)
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
    }
  getContact() {
   this.getData().subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data
})


  }
}
```

When I use Postman and send a request to the server through the api, I am getting json response back => in headers I am sending a key: "Autorization" and value: "tokenexample".
My app is running on the localhost.
Can you help me please with this?

Comment: All the access-... headers should be set server side

Comment: Why should it be different if Postman handles the request?

Comment: read about CORS, which browsers implement (but not rest cients, such as postman)

Comment: 'ERROR service_base_v1.createErrorResponse: Error: Missing Authorization header at velocity_core/forms/rest_base/isAllowed:16 (isAllowed)' this is what I read in log of the server.

Comment: You need to set the `Authorization` header client side. It is the `Access-...` headers that need to be set server side

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side it should be enough to just set the following:

```
    // add authorization header with jwt token
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization', 
            'Basic exampletokenexampletokenexampletoken' });

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

This tells the server your Authorization.

On the server side you should set the CORS header: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*'
'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Authorization' you should only set on the server side if that is not done by a framework or the webserver configuration.

For development you can work without the server side header. If you use Chrome it will display a small icon on the right side of the address field. If you click that you can allow unseucre content on the page.

To explain why it works in Postman: Postman ignores the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from the server side. This is a browser security function (like David explained).